# How do I reflect changes made to ViewModels for other windows?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

My app contains the following moduls:

**SystemModel** --> **SystemViewModel** --> **SystemWindow**

**SettingsModel** --> **SettingsViewModel** --> **SettingsWindow**

My **SystemViewModel** contain **SettingsViewModel** and other things.
In my **SystemViewModel** I create some **Instance** that its ctor receives **SettingsViewModel**.

If i want to update the settings I opened new **SettingsWindow** as *ShowDialog* with **SettingsViewModel** as him *DataContext*. If the user click "ok" I update the settings else I don't update.

My problem is that I dont know how to update the **Settings** in the **Instance** that I created in the **SystemViewModel** (**Instance** that received **SettingsViewModel** in his ctor).

Any idea?

Comment: I can add some code later if its needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create only one instance of settings view model, maybe residing in a common view model that serves kind of a root for the view model and providing the glue that binds the models together?

Something like a view model controller, even if this sound a bit strange. This root view model could react to events from the view models and then can do everything that is required to update the other settings.

Another approach is a messaging based approach like the one that is implemented by MVVM Light Toolit. I have used this once and after the project got rather big this approach was kind of complicated regarding maintenance.

**Update:**

You can find information about MVVM Light Toolkit [here](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/).